# Is it possible to give a regex as a 3rd argument to maketrans()?

Tags: python

As far as I know `maketrans()` can take up to three args.

In this case, the 3rd argument stands for characters that will be mapped to nothing. Is there a way to give a regex there?

The reason I am asking is because I'd like to be able to take advantage of the method's ability to map some characters to some other characters at the same time (the usage of the first two args).

Comment: No; per the [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) *"If there is a third argument, it must be a string, whose characters will be mapped to `None` in the result."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe In that case, isn't r"some_regex" a string too?

Comment: Yes, but it's still not going to be treated as a regular expression. The `r` just means "raw".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there a way to give a regex there?*

[maketrans docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) says

> This static method returns a translation table usable for
> str.translate().
>
> If there is only one argument, it must be a dictionary mapping Unicode
> ordinals (integers) or characters (strings of length 1) to Unicode
> ordinals, strings (of arbitrary lengths) or None. Character keys will
> then be converted to ordinals.
>
> If there are two arguments, they must be strings of equal length, and
> in the resulting dictionary, each character in x will be mapped to the
> character at the same position in y. If there is a third argument, it
> must be a string, whose characters will be mapped to None in the
> result.

So last argument is required to be string. However you might craft own object to be used in `translate` method, which have to support `__getitem__` method which would be feed with Unicode ordinal (integer) of character and has to return Unicode ordinal (integer) or str or `None`. Consider following example which drop odd digits:

```
class OddRemover:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in range(49,58,2):  # 49 is ASCII code for digit 1
            return None
        else:
            return key
odd_rem = OddRemover()
text = 'somestring235700'
print(text.translate(odd_rem))
```

output:

```
somestring200
```